# how to Fabricate object for mongo model with constructor that requires arguments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mongoid, fabrication-gem

I have a class

```
class Transaction
    include Mongoid::Document

    belongs_to :objectA
    belongs_to :objectB

    def initialize(objectA, objectB)
        super
        @objectA = objectA
        @objectB = objectB
    end
end
```

Now I am trying to put together a `Fabricator`

```
Fabricator(:transaction) do
     on_init do
        init_with(Fabricate(:klassA), Fabricate(:klassB))
     end
end
```

I have already created `Fabricator(:klassA)` and `Fabricator(:klassB)` which work just fine.

I keep getting this error message:

`` NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for #<Fabrication::Schematic::Attribute:0x007f9361b59950> ``

I am fairly certain that it is related to the initialize method. If I remove the constructor it works.

Mongo version 2.4.1
fabrication (2.6.4)
rails (3.2.11)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because your `super` call will pass your custom arguments to the `Mongoid::Document` initializer that expects (up to) two hashes, not two objects.
The solution is either to call `super()`, it will pass no arguments, or to rewrite the constructor to pass only additional arguments:

```
def initialize(objectA, objectB, args = nil, options = nil)
    super(args, options) 
    @objectA = objectA
    @objectB = objectB
end
```